# How to identify points on a contour plot where partial derivative with respect to an independent variable is positive?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the Multivariable Calculus course hosted at OCW MIT website, the following question is posted. Identifying points on a contour plot where partial derivative with respect to an independent variable is zero or positive

[image]

The solution is provided as follows: identified points on contour plot where partial derivative with respect to y is zero or positive[image: image2]

Can someone explain this to me. I have already gone through the lecture and books on related contents for a number of times. But still can't convince myself as to how df/dy > 0 in those highlighted portion of the contour plot?

Answer (score 0):

The condition $\partial f/\partial y \geq 0$, means that $f$ is increasing with respect to $y$ along lines of constant $x$. So at each point along the level curve $f = 2000$, look at how the function is changing along a line of constant $x$. For example, consider a point $(x,y)$ in one of the shaded regions of the level curve $f = 2000$. Then judging from the contour plot, $f(x,y-\epsilon) \leq f(x,y) = 2000 \leq f(x,y+\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon > 0$ sufficiently small.
Thus, $f$ appears to be increasing locally is this direction. At the points marked by solid dots, the contour plot shows that $f$ does not change locally along lines of constant $x$ through these points. I hope this helps to clarify the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first, I didn't understand your explanation but now I got it.